# How to make a nested loop to extract elements that i need from the list

Tags: r, list, loops, for-loop, nested

In Rstudio I have a list with 8 objects in it, each one of it contains elements. Im tryin to extract them by interwals. I have two values to define interwals. The first value stands for the begining of the interval, the second one is for the end.
How should I do this in a propper way?

I wrote down a simple function with a nested loop, that takes objects from my list and extract the elements that I need:

```
new_func <- function(x, y) { # x and y are values that stands for interwals

  # list with objects
  mylist <- list_1 

  # vector that will contain elements of the list's objects
  vector_of_elem_fr_list <- c()

  # new list with objects that contain extracted elements
  copy_list <- list()

  for (i in length(mylist)){
    vector_of_elem_fr_list <- mylist[[i]]

    # vector with extracted elements
    vector_11 <- c()
    p <- 1

    for (j in 1:length(x)) { # x and y has the same length
      vector_11 <- c(vector_11, vector_of_elem_fr_list[c(x[j]:y[j])])
      p <- p + 1
      if (p == 20) {
        copy_list[[i]] <- vector_11
      }
    }
  }
  return(copy_list)
}
```

I also added the "p" value to count down the whole cycle of inner loop and only then put the vector in the new list. 
But the function returns a list with empty objects except for the last one that contains correctly extracted elements. Please help.
Here is [a link](https://filecloud.me/eraoqpjfwjtm.html) of dputed nested list

Comment: Please `dput` your nested list or at least replicate an example for us with desired results.

Comment: Done, I've put the link of the dputed nested list

Comment: Do not ask us to download files. Because `dput` outputs an ascii version of object, it can be placed in body of post. If too long, consider [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/) or [rextester.com (R compiler)](https://rextester.com/l/r_online_compiler). Then send us the link.